# HTML Form Checkbox Can't output values in PHP

Tags: php, html

I am relatively new to HTML and PHP languages. I am making a survey form and using checkboxes to allow the user to select all of the classes they feel were most useful during their time in college.

In my HTML code, I have the following form element:

```
<table>
    <tr>
        <td>
            <input type="checkbox" name="useful_classes[]" value="Engineering Economics">
            <td align="left">Engineering Economics
            </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>
            <input type="checkbox" name="useful_classes[]" value="Operations Research">
            <td align="left">Operations Research
            </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>
            <input type="checkbox" name="useful_classes[]" value="Simulation">
            <td align="left">Simulation
            </td>
    </tr>
</table>
```

And below here is my PHP code that I'm trying to use to make a submission page for them to verify everything they just submitted is correct. I can't figure out how to get the PHP code to output the things like "Engineering Economics, Operations Research" or something like that. No matter what I try from other things I've found on google, none of it works.

```
<?PHP
            $useful_classes = $_POST['useful_classes'];

            print <<<END_PRINT
            <table>

                <tr>
                    <td class="title" align="right" > <b>Most Useful Classes:</b> </td>
                    <td class="values" align="left" > 
                        foreach ($useful_classes as $useful_classes){ 
        echo $useful_classes . ", ";
    }
                            /* for($i=0; $i<count($useful_classes); $i++){
                                echo($useful_classes[$i]);
    if($i !=$N){
                                    echo(", ");
                                }
                            } */
                    </td>
                </tr>
            </table>
    END_PRINT;
    ?>
```

Any help is appreciated!

Comment: you realize that if that is your actual code, there is a parse error happening in the background, but you didn't check for errors.

Comment: you also have no form, so that is another issue

Answer (score 1):

```
<?PHP
    if(isset($_POST['submit']))
    {
        $useful_classes = $_POST['useful_classes'];
?>
        <table>
            <tr>
                <td class="title" align="right" > <b>Most Useful Classes:</b> </td>
                <td class="values" align="left" > 
                <?php
                    foreach ($useful_classes as $useful_classes){ 
                        echo $useful_classes . ",";
                    }
                ?>

                </td>
            </tr>
        </table>
<?php 
    }
?>

<form action="" method="post">
<table>
    <tr>
        <td>
            <input type="checkbox" name="useful_classes[]" value="Engineering Economics">
            <td align="left">Engineering Economics
            </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>
            <input type="checkbox" name="useful_classes[]" value="Operations Research">
            <td align="left">Operations Research
            </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>
            <input type="checkbox" name="useful_classes[]" value="Simulation">
            <td align="left">Simulation
            </td>
    </tr>
    <input type="submit" name="submit">
</table>
</form>
```

And Instead Of This You Can Easily Do it By [Implode Function](https://www.w3schools.com/php/func_string_implode.asp)

```
if(isset($_POST['submit']))
    {
        echo   $useful_classes = implode(",",$_POST['useful_classes']);

    }
```